# SignalR Server and Client in same assembly, howto specify hub

Tags: c#, server, client, signalr, signalr-hub

When I implement a SignalR Server and Client in the same library, how to tell the server which `hubs` to use?

My first try was:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
    hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    hubConfiguration.EnableJavaScriptProxies = false;
    hubConfiguration.Resolver.Resolve<TeamHubServer>();

    app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
}
```

It seems that all `classes` that inherit from `Hub` are registered.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a class that inherits from Hub

```
public class ExampleHub : Hub
```

then override this two methods

```
public override Task OnConnected()
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
```

and you will be able to define new methods in the ExampleHub class

After all this you will call the method as following:

```
var con = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ExampleHub>();
con.Clients.All.addNew(param);
```